# How can i build my spring boot project by setting the project locale manually

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm-arguments

I am using hibernate-jpamodelgen to generate static classes for my entities. When I run "mvn clean install" with vm options "-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US", the classes are generated correctly, but when I run "build and run" command in Intellij Idea, it builds project and generates problematic characters in static files. My default Locale is tr_TR.

problematic-character

[image: 1]

For now, i can run the project by build with maven ["clean install" + vm options] configuration in Intellij and run it with [Do not build before run] option in Intellij. How can I configure the project structure and settings to ensure proper build operation of the project and generate proper classes

Comment: What encoding is set in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Encodings"?

Comment: -Global Encoding: UTF-8
-Project Encoding: System default windows-1254
-src\main\java: UTF-8

Comment: Does it help to switch project encoding to UTF-8? Also you  may pass VM options used in Maven to IDE build in "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler"

Comment: No it doensn't work. When i try to build it with UTF-8 it creates problematic char and when i try to build it with windows-1254, it makes small 'i' letter 'İ' which is included in Turkish alphabet but I just want to build and run it by configuring it's language en-US

Comment: I think best solution for now, is running project with maven command  [mvn spring-boot:run + -Duser.language=en-US]

Comment: I set my Idea Vm Options by adding "Duser.language=en" and it worked properly